# How do you set the scale for Ruby Money?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I'm using [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) and [google_currency](https://github.com/RubyMoney/google_currency) to handle the money component in my rails application. I'm having trouble when I try to convert a variable from PHP to USD.

If I try to run this:

```
Money.new("15", "PHP").exchange_to("USD")
```

I'm getting:

```
#<Money fractional:0 currency:USD>
```

The reason why this is happening is because the rate for PHP to USD is small, and it's rounding off to 0. Does anyone know how to set the default scale when using exchange_to to avoid this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Money.new('15', 'PHP')` means `0.15 PHP` or just 15 Centavos. That is (based on the current exchange rate) arround `0.003 USD` or rounded `0.00 USD`.

Did you perhaps mean `Money.new('15_00', 'PHP')`?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly it. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks! :)